# comparison of random_bytes fails when values match

Tags: php, php-7, nonce

Brief but interesting one here.  I probably have something odd here, but I've lost a few hours now and can't find out what is the issue.

I have a function that produces a nonce, like so.  It's not very complex at the moment, but is more an experimentation of a concept that is new to me.  I'm using random_bytes as the natural successor to `mcrypt_create_iv` for PHP7+:

```
$token = random_bytes(16);
```

this is then stored like so:

```
$session->add('nonce',$token);

(which is essentially....)
$_SESSION[$var] = $val;
```

whilst simultaneously being used in my form, like so:

```
<input name="token" type="hidden" value="<?=$token?>">
```

The form submits and passes through some validation and so on.  As part of this, I retrieve both values:

```
$token = $_POST['token'];
$nonce = $session->get('nonce');
```

and then I have a validation point for further execution - only proceed if the two values match.  Problem is, I can't actually get them to validate.  Neither of these current output true:

```
if(hash_equals($nonce, $token))
if($nonce === $token)
```

`var_dump`shows both are strings of equal length, but for some reason they aren't comparable. Both values look like they match.

```
if(hash_equals($nonce, $nonce))
```

equals to true (as you'd expect), so I can only assume that one of the values is becoming altered along the way, either by `$_POST` or via my retrieval function (which literally just reads from the session).

I'd appreciate any help/suggestions with this - I'm either overlooking something obvious, or too inexperienced with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all random byte values are valid directly in HTML. If the string contains values outside of the regular sequence of ascii letters and numbers (`[0-9a-zA-z]`), anything can happen if you don't escape it for the HTML context. You can use `htmlspecialchars` to escape the values if necessary, or use a hash or base64 encoded version of the random bytes instead.

A good example would be if the ascii value of `"` is contained in the 16 random bytes, your HTML attribute will end early. HTML isn't very fond of control sequences (low ascii characters) or letters outside of the current encoding (if UTF-8, any value above 127 will need to be a valid UTF-8 codepoint when viewed across multiple bytes).

Comment: Excellent - I have amended my function to `$token = base64_encode(random_bytes(16));`, which now works.   I knew it would be something simple, but you are a legend nonetheless!